# Node.js send Server input to Client. Warning about memory leak. What is my mistake? And how does node.js run code?

Tags: node.js, io, server, client

Server:

```
var net = require('net');
var stdin = process.openStdin();

var client_list = [];

var server = net.createServer(function(connection) { 
    //console.log('client connected');

    connection.on('error', function(e){
        if(e.code == 'ECONNRESET'){
        console.log('Client dissconeccted');
        }
    });
    //connection.write('Hello World!\r\n');
    stdin.addListener("data", function(d) {
    // note:  d is an object, and when converted to a string it will
    // end with a linefeed.  so we (rather crudely) account for that  
    // with toString() and then trim()

    console.log("you entered: [" + d.toString().trim() + "]");
        connection.write(d.toString().trim());
    });
    connection.pipe(connection);

});
server.listen(9999, function() { 
    console.log('server is listening');
});
```

Client:

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 9999;
//var client = new net.Socket();

    var client = net.connect(PORT, HOST, function(){
        console.log('connected to server! ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
        //client.write('I am Superman');
    });

    client.on('data', function(data) {
        var data = data.toString();
        console.log(data);

        //If data starts with JS add injection functionallity
        if (data === "END"){
            client.end();
            console.log("ENDING!")
        }
        else if (data === "poo"){
            console.log("HOLY SHIT!")
        }
    });

    //Keep trying to connect!
    client.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Parent connection error');
        //client.end();
        client.connect(PORT, HOST);
    });

    client.on('end', function() { 
        console.log('disconnected from server');
    });

/*var client = net.connect({port: 8080}, function() {
    console.log('connected to server!');  
});*/
```

So what happens is that it keeps adding listeners(?) and warns me at 11 listeners with the message:

> "Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 data listeners added.
>   Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit".

Why is this? I have tried fixing this by moving `stdin.addListener()` but it either doesn't take the input at all or the problem persists. Am I onto something? And how is code run in node, is it a loop?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have run both the client and server scripts. I can't reproduce the error message that you're getting. I'm running the code on Ubuntu - nodejs 6.9.5, npm 5.4.2. Could you post the contents of your `package.json` file?

Update: had a look online. seems like a known old bug in Node. https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/5108

Comment: {
  "name": "tcp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Tcp client/server test",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Juliet",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "net": "^1.0.2"
  }
}